# What is a good mobile application testing training plan?

Tags: mobile

As per my understanding, I have created following training plan. Please review and let me know if I'm missing something or anything needs to be update?

**Topics**
**Introduction to Mobile Testing**

1. What is Mobile application testing?
2. Why is Mobile testing important?
3. What do you need to be a good mobile tester?
4. Types of Mobile Applications
5. Mobile Application SDLC

**Mobile web applications**

1. Overview
2. Types of Mobile web apps:

   a) Non-responsive applications

   b) Responsive applications
3. Testing mobile web apps
4. Technologies used to develop

**Native Mobile Applications**

1. Overview
2. Types of Native apps:

   a) Device-specific applications

   b) Responsive applications

   c) Hybrid applications
3. Testing native apps
4. Technologies

   a) OS API

   b) App Store

   c) Device capabilities

**Unique Mobile Testing Considerations**

1. User Experience
2. Network
3. Data Storage
4. Operating system
5. Jail Breaking
6. Hardware/Device capabilities
7. Security

**Mobile Testing Platforms**

1. Introduction
2. Desktop browsers
3. Mobile Emulation
4. Cloud Testing - AWS Device Farm
5. Physical Device testing
6. Remote Device testing

**Mobile Testing Techniques**

1. Exploratory Testing
2. Device Access
3. Security Testing
4. Performance Testing
5. Compatibility Testing
6. Submission Guideline Testing

**Tools for Mobile Testing**

1. Multi platform testing tools
2. Android Testing tools
3. iOS Testing tools
4. BlackBerry Testing tools
5. Windows Mobile Testing tools
6. Remote Device Access Services.
7. Outsource/Crowd source testing services

Comment: performance testing and load testing plays a key role add it

Comment: You have responsive, hybrid and native apps under native as well as having responsive and hybrid under mobile web.  Does the former make sense given the separation you've created?

Comment: ALSO - you should make the question "what is a good training plan for mobile?" and *then* post the content as an _answer_  It's ok to answer your own question btw.  That way people can vote on it, provide alternatives, etc.

Comment: What is the audience for this training plan? Newly hired web-experienced testers? New hires with no testing background? Just anyone interested in mobile application testing? All training plans should be tailored to the needs of the trainees.

Comment: Your are welcome @AshrafAhmad its how the site works best to give you and others good answers.  I would still consider doing it

Comment: Audience is mixed, newly hired as well as experienced testers

Answer (score 2):

Below testing techniques can be added to the training plan:

- Usability Testing
- Recoverability Testing
- Installation/Uninstallation Testing

Answer (score 0):

Geofencing testing is a must for our team because geofencing requires employees that are punching in (or punching out) to be within a specified proximity range of an assigned location. For example, a gaming industry employee would be restricted to punching in using their mobile app within 20 feet of a specific door to the casino.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why geofencing testing matters for your team and what situations would make it important for a mobile application?

Comment: Edited to better explain.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest Interrupt Testing is also must. In Interrupt testing we checks how our application behaves if we gets any phone call if we are using the application.
Sometime the data syncing is affected if we gets a phone call in between a sync process.

Comment: Can you give an example or a scenario to explain this?